# Select com datas de vencimento

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

Como resolver esta questão.

```
ID      status      valor    vencimento    clienteID

1220    Pendente    37,00    2019-02-20    2888
3146    Pendente    37,00    2019-03-20    2888
3147    Pendente    37,00    2019-04-07    2888
3148    Pendente    37,00    2019-05-15    2888
3149    Pendente    37,00    2018-06-20    2888
```

Estou precisando de ajuda no seguinte caso.

Tenho essa tabela acima. Preciso pegar os dados das contas vencidas até o mês atual e mais do mês seguinte desse cliente, independente do dia de vencimento, que seriam as seguintes:

```
37,00    2019-02-20

37,00    2019-03-20

37,00    2019-04-07

37,00    2018-06-20
```

Não estou conseguindo fazer isto, já tentei várias maneira, mas listam as do ano corrente e não inclui a dos anos passados.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que você esteja se referindo à linguagem SQL.

```
SELECT valor, vencimento
    FROM sua_tabela
    WHERE status = 'Pendente' AND
        vencimento < date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE + interval '2 month');
```

Dependendo do SGBD que esteja utilizando a função para calcular o primeiro dia do segundo mês posterior pode ser diferente.

Comment: Desculpe não ter informado o banco e a linguagem, mas é MySQL e PHP.
Não sei a referência de date_trunc no mysql.

Comment: Tente:
vencimento < DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH);

Answer (score 0):

Voce não informou qual o banco está usando e nem se o comando será a partir de alguma linguagem/ambiente especifico, criei um exemplo com o MySQL 5.6, embora vc também não tenha informado, considerei o campo status como indicativo se o lancamento foi pago (`liquidado`) ou está vencido (`pendente`), criei alguns dados, ficticios e o comando SQL:

**Criando o schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `vencimento` date,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `status`, `vencimento`) VALUES
  ('1220', 'pendente', '2018-02-20'),
  ('3146', 'pago', '2018-03-20'),
  ('3147', 'pendente', '2019-03-20'),
  ('3148', 'pago', '2019-03-20'),
  ('3149', 'pendente', '2019-03-22'),
  ('3150', 'pendente', '2019-03-25'),
  ('3151', 'pendente', '2019-04-07'),
  ('3152', 'pendente', '2019-05-15');
```

---

**Montagem da query (considerando que o primeiro registro foi criado em 2014) #1**

```
SELECT 
    * FROM test
WHERE 
    vencimento BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d') 
    AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d')
    AND status='pendente';
```

**Resultado:**

```
| id   | status   | vencimento |
| ---- | -------- | ---------- |
| 1220 | pendente | 2018-02-20 |
| 3147 | pendente | 2019-03-20 |
| 3149 | pendente | 2019-03-22 |
| 3150 | pendente | 2019-03-25 |
```

---

*Obs.:*
O exemplo serve para voce selecionar quaisquer intervalo de data, e facilmente adaptada para qq banco.

[Veja funcionando no DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aK7ZfUkAQ8V1wvVfTj8hiD/1)

Comment: Desculpe, o bd é MySQL e a linguagem é PHP.

Comment: Nessa parte , AND STR_TO_DATE('2019-04-30', '%Y-%m-%d'), como poderia saber o ultimo dia de cada mês ?

Comment: Em mysql vc pode obter com `last_day(data)`

Answer (score 0):

muito obrigado pelas resposta. Consegui resolver, depois de muitas pesquisas, como abaixo, pegando o exemplo do Sido

$dia_atual  = date("d");

SELECT 
    * FROM test
WHERE 
    vencimento <= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL (DAY(LAST_DAY(DATE(NOW())))-$dia_atual) DAY;